# Help Needed: Installation and Display Issues on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I hope this message finds you well. I'm reaching out to seek assistance with an issue I've encountered while trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop (HP Pavilion DK2095TX) with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Laptop GPU (4 GB GDDR6 dedicated). I'm facing two distinct scenarios:

Scenario 1: Installation Error - Unable to Install GRUB
During the installation process, when I choose "Something else" as the installation type, I encounter the error message: "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme0n1. This is a fatal error." This issue prevents me from completing the installation using this method. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully install Ubuntu with this setup.

Scenario 2: Black Screen After Installation
In another attempt, I chose the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option. The installation itself completes without errors. However, after I log in to the user account, I'm faced with a persistent black screen. I suspect this might be related to the NVIDIA graphics card, but I'm unsure about how to proceed in order to resolve this issue.

My laptop specifications are as follows:

Model: HP Pavilion DK2095TX
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Laptop GPU (4 GB GDDR6 dedicated)
I'm reaching out to the Ubuntu Community for assistance and advice on troubleshooting these issues. If anyone has encountered similar problems or has insights into resolving them, I would be grateful for your guidance.

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm looking forward to your suggestions and recommendations.